# How to make the graph's axis skip fixed values (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the example below, how to make the graph's y-axis show values skipping from 25 to 25?

**Input Code:**

```
library(ggplot2)

# scatter plot
graph <-ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + 
        geom_point() +
        ylim(0,150) +
        xlim(0,30) +
        labs(y = 'y-axis', x = "x-axis") +
        theme_classic()
graph
```

**Output of Input code:**
[image]

I read several tutorials and I couldn't find this function. Below are some tutorial links I read:

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-scales-and-transformations

https://ggplot2-book.org/scales.html

[some others...]

Comment: [http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for scale_y_continuous:

```
 # scatter plot
 graph <-ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + 
   geom_point() +
   #ylim(0,150) +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 150, by=25), limits=c(0,150))+
   xlim(0,30) +
   labs(y = 'y-axis', x = "x-axis") +
   theme_classic()
 graph
```